# Google Extension - Call SendRequest After Page being loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a google extension which suppose to perform multiple tasks when the page is loaded and call the background script methods whenever the client press on an update button.

The reason I have to work with the background script is that I need to send information to a different server and actually bypass the cross origin policy.

Also, I'm using "chrome.extension.sendRequest" for various actions - the first instance started when the page is loaded and it's work fine. I got stuck when I'm trying to call the "sendRequest" in the second time after the page is already loaded.
It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined

Does anyone know how can I call the background script and use it even after the page is loaded?

p.s, I'm not using any GUI and html pages - only js.

Comment: it's a very massive code... I would need only a direction for accessing the background script code.

Comment: Without any context, your question is not going to be answered. At least show the parts which cause the error.

Comment: The sendRequest doesn't resopnd after the page has loaded: http://pastebin.com/4Rrcbn9Q

And that is the background page: http://pastebin.com/JJyHbFfp

Comment: Assuming that the `check_tag` function  is called, there are a few problems: 1. The URL is a relative URL. In the background page, this resolves to a page in the extension's directory. 2. Have you added the URL to the `permissions` section in the manifest file? This is mandatory. 3. In recent Chrome versions, you don't need a background page to fetch cross-origin HTTP requests.

Comment: yes I did.
Also, As I said before, In the first time it works, but in the second time it doesn't recognize any function.

Comment: The `chrome.extension is undefined` error indicates that the second time, you're not running code in the context of an extension. Fix that (or show the full extension's code if you're still stuck)